# Parámetros de conversión JObject

Tags: c#, json, webservice, poo, cast

Estoy realizando una integración con un servicio Web que me retorna un JSON, dependiendo del resultado me puede retornar una lista (`List<Detalles>`) o si es un único valor un objeto únicamente `Detalles`.

Esta es mi clase:

```
public class ConsultaCertificacionPago
{
    public string dato1 { get; set; }
    public List<Detalle> detalles { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando el resultado del servicio Web es un único valor, el JSON lo retorna como una propiedad, algo así:

```
public class ConsultaCertificacionPago
{
    public string dato1 { get; set; }
    public Detalle detalles { get; set; }
}
```

Por consiguiente me genera un error al hacer el *cast* de un objeto tipo `JObject`:

```
objectNative.ToObject<ConsultaCertificacionPago>();
```

¿Es posible realizar esta conversión, incluyendo los dos tipos de JSON que pueda devolver el servicio Web, es decir, una propiedad como lista de objetos y otra como un objeto único?

Y cuando se cumpla al última condición adicionar un único objeto a la lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder realizar lo que tú deseas, nos vamos a apoyar de un tipo de dato dinámico llamado `dynamic` para poder determinar qué estamos recibiendo en la segunda variable del JSON. Primero veamos la definición de las clases:

```
public class ConsultaCertificacionPago
{
    public string dato1 { get; set; }
    public List<Detalle> detalles { get; set; }
}

public class Detalle
{
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Date cuenta que la clase `ConsultaCertificacionPago` siempre va a tener una definición `List<Detalle>` para la propiedad `detalles`.

Después, vamos a manejar la sección detalles del JSON. Lo vamos a meter en una variable dinámica y a su vez, lo vamos a comparar para saber qué tipo de dato es. La validación quedaría `if (objDetalles is Detalle)`. Si la condición resulta verdadera, se agregará ese objeto como un elemento más de la lista `detalles`, caso contrario, se deserializa el objeto directamente a `ConsultaCertificacionPago`. Aquí puedes ver el código completo:

```
try
{
    ConsultaCertificacionPago objConsultaCertificacionPago = new ConsultaCertificacionPago();

    JObject detallesJSON = JObject.Parse(json);
    detallesJSON = (JObject)detallesJSON["detalles"];

    dynamic objDetalles = detallesJSON.ToObject<dynamic>();

    if (objDetalles is Detalle)
    {
        objConsultaCertificacionPago.detalles.Add(objDetalles);
    }
    else {
        objConsultaCertificacionPago = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConsultaCertificacionPago>(json);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Manejo de la excepción
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que manejes la conversión a un `Dictionary<string, Object>` y extraes la variable detalles como un object la cual tendrás que validar si es uno o varios elementos o si el elemento puede ser convertido a una lista, en fin, con el reflect api puedes validar con propiedades ya sea del Objeto List o del Objeto ConsultaCertificacionPago.

Lo anterior es porque el Objeto ConsultaCertificacionPago no tiene ninguna relacion con el Objeto List<> lo que hace que no se pueda usar casting para manejarlos.